# cannot execute jquery after on append html

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am appending html by taking code from *data-prototype* attribute from one div.

The problem is this that I am appending with two select boxes on which I want to run later jquery, as I want to update second one after choosing option from first one, it is just not executing jQuery code. Everything is alright on select boxes which are inserted when page is loading, but for those from append it doesn't work.

My jQuery Code:

```
var $optionDefinitions = $('.option-definitions');
var collectionHolder = $('div#epos_productsbundle_variant_options');
var $addOptionsLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_options_link">Add an option</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addOptionsLink);

$(function() {
    collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
    collectionHolder.data('index', collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addOptionsLink.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addOptionsForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });

    function addOptionsForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
        var prototype = collectionHolder.data('prototype');
        var index = collectionHolder.data('index');
        var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
        var $newFormLi = $('<li id="subform_'+index+'"></li>').append(newForm);

        $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
        collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
    }


   $optionDefinitions.change(function(event){
       var $optionid = $(this).val();
       var url = '{{ path('variant_options', {'id': 'optionid' }) }}'
       url = url.replace("optionid", $optionid)
       $.ajax({
           url: url,
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(data){
              $(event.target).next('select').html(data);
           },
           error: function(){
             alert('failure');
           }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. After append I should use *[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)*.

**So instead of**

```
$optionDefinitions.change(function(event){
   var $optionid = $(this).val();
   var url = '{{ path('variant_options', {'id': 'optionid' }) }}'
   url = url.replace("optionid", $optionid)
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(data){
          $(event.target).next('select').html(data);
       },
       error: function(){
         alert('failure');
       }
    });
})
```

**I got know**

```
$(body).on('change', $optionDefinitions, function(event){
   var $optionid = $(event.target).val();
   var url = '{{ path('variant_options', {'id': 'optionid' }) }}'
   url = url.replace("optionid", $optionid)
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(data){
          $(event.target).next('select').html(data);
       },
       error: function(){
         alert('failure');
       }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack.  setTimeout(after, 1);

```
 93             var self = this;
 94             var after = function() {
 95                 self. _container = $("#container");
 96                 self._slidebox = $("#slidebox");                                                                      
 97                 self._slidebox_icon = $("#slidebox_icon");
 98             }  
 99            
100             setTimeout(after,1);
```